# How to validate a column based on the value in another column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, column, validation, column-validation

I'm trying to come up with a formula that could validate a column.

I have a form in SharePoint to register parcel shipments. There's a column that contains a shipment code (values 1, 2, 3).

If the value in the column [shipment code] = 1, the column [Country name] must contain a country name (can't be blank).

If the value in the column [shipment code] is 2 or 3, the column [Country name] must be kept empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **SharePoint list validation settings** for this requirement.

Assuming [shipment code] is choice field and has only 3 choices (1,2 and 3).
Try something like below formula:

```
=IF([shipment code]=1,IF(ISBLANK([Country name]),false,true),IF(ISBLANK([Country name]),true,false))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).